# Why perl $$ prototype not grab two arguments

Tags: perl, prototype

I read now http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=861966
But I have a question about internals

What is cause that prototype sub atan2($$); not cause the parser to grab only two arguments:

So

```
@a = (atan2 1, 2, 3);
```

does not become

```
@a = (atan2(1, 2), 3);
```

What is a cause to not allow perl to do that?

Comment: A guess (not an answer): Maybe because it would be time-consuming to implement in the parser, have exceptions, and be of questionable benefit even where it could be made to work. IMO the second line of code is far easier for a human to read, and the cost of doing it is well worth that payback.

Comment: You do know that you should not use prototypes, right? You don't really need them for anything. Their only use is to make subroutines that emulate how some of the built-in functions work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading documentation more accuracy. I have found this:
**"a list operator tends to gobble up all the arguments that follow it**"
and only after gobbling parser checks count of that arguments to much prototype.
It seems the prototyping is like **to constraint a number of arguments** a function can take.

So we do not allow parser to grab two, three, four argument
because this will break main rule:

1. **"a list operator tends to gobble up all the arguments that follow it**"
2. If we break that rule, it will confuse reader. What does this mean:

   say atan2 1, 2, 3, 4;

   - say atan2( 1, 2 ), 3, 4;
   - say atan2( 1, 2 , 3), 4;
   - say atan2( 1, 2 , 3, 4 );

thus force programmer to read source code.

.

What about unary?

DOC: **unary operators are treated as functions with one argument.**

They are exception because of unary functions are simple and easily noticeable. It is hard to think wrong when you see unary. So it is OK, to grab one argument, but allowing grab two, three etc arguments make source ambiguous

Comment: You can simulate to grab two arguments and do not touch others with some trick: `sub test { my $a = shift @_; my $b = shift @_; my $c = calculate( $a, $b ); return ($c, @_); } say 1,2,test 3,4,5,6;`

Answer (score 5):

It would be extremely misleading to the reader, and forgetting the parens would fail silently (in your example, at least). I can't think of any reason you'd want that behaviour.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer.

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, How does giving two excellent reasons for not doing something not answer why that thing isn't done?

Comment: @ikegami it doesn't fail silently, calling a function prototyped like atan($$) with more than 2 arguments yields a syntax error at compile time.

Comment: @Ben Grimm, Re-read the question. The OP didn't ask what the current behaviour of prototypes is. He asked why `atan2 1, 2, 3` doesn't mean `atan2(1, 2), 3`.

Comment: @AtanuCSE This does provide an answer, the OP is asking why the language was designed one way and not another.  Prototypes are about forcing context, but they're also about avoiding errors.  One could go through the perl5-porters mailing list archive and see if there was ever any debate.

Comment: @AtanuCSE, How does giving two excellent reasons for not doing something not answer why that thing isn't done?

Answer (score 1):

Perl passes lists of parameters to functions, and `1, 2, 3` is a list. An exception to this rule is a monadic function (e.g. `sub func($) { ... }`) which is handled in a special way to allow you to construct lists like this in a very natural way:

```
sub double($) { $_[0] * 2 }
sub triple($) { $_[0] * 3 }
my @a = (1, double 2, triple 3, 4);
```

Apart from the special cases, the parser handles all function calls the same way, with the *entire list* following the function name being compared to the prototype, if any. When the type(s) and/or length do not match, the compiler throws a syntax error.

Comment: The question is, *why*?

Comment: The OP is asking the question from the wrong perspective. Prototypes exist to assist in type checking and allow user functions to work in the same manner as builtins -- not to break or override something as fundamental as list syntax. That a monadic function even *appears* to pull a single item out of a list is an exceptional case in Perl's grammar.

Comment: @Ben Grimm, Backwards. Prototypes actually change parsing rules and semantics. They don't provide any type checking. (e.g. `perl -E'sub foo ($) { } foo(@a); say "ok"'`) That's why people are told to avoid prototypes when they start using them for type checking.

Comment: @ikegami I need to dig deeper to fully understand it, but the apidoc above `ck_entersub_args_proto` in `op.c` states that prototypes provide type checking (among other things). `@a` in your example is converted to a scalar because it _can_ be -- and there is nothing wrong with that so long as everyone understands what's going on -- but passing a scalar to a function which expects a coderef will yield an error.

Comment: You can't specify that a code ref is expected. You can specify that the sub call's arguments must start with a block. When you do, you can't pass a code ref any more than another reference. You will receive a code ref, but only because the user passed a block  in the call.

Comment: `sub t(&) {}   t(\&t);` only works because the argument type is checked.

Comment: `sub t(&) {} $r=\&t;  t($r);` doesn't work, so it's a syntax restriction, not a type check.

Comment: Fair enough -- the parser can only know that `$r` is a scalar unless it is cast `\&$r`.

Comment: And the nail in the coffin, `sub t(&) {} t(\@a);` also works (until 5.22)

Comment: Okay, in contrast to `$, % and @`, the code for `&` only checks what the argument _[is not](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob?f=op.c#l11425)_. That has to be a bug.

Comment: It is. As I mentioned, this has been fixed in 5.22

Comment: Gotcha - mistook that to mean you had tested on the latest dev release. But I see that it was fixed in [5.21.7](http://search.cpan.org/~xsawyerx/perl-5.21.9/pod/perl5217delta.pod#&_and_\&_prototypes_accepts_only_subs).